# Cannot convert parameter - Conversion loses qualifiers

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm frequently troubled by const correctness, and this seems to be no exception. Please advise me why the following code wont compile:

```
class string_token_stream
{
    public:

    typedef wchar_t* string_type;

    string_token_stream(const string_type input_string)
        : _input_string(input_string)
    {
    }

    private:

    const string_type _input_string;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const wchar_t *str = get_a_string_somewhere();
    string_token_stream sts(str);
    //                      ^------ Compile-time error C2664.
    return 0;
}
```

The error given is:

```
error C2664: 'string_token_stream::string_token_stream(const string_token_stream::string_type)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t *' to 'const string_token_stream::string_type'
1>          Conversion loses qualifiers
```

I'm compiling on Visual C++ 2010 Express. Additional compile/linker options available upon request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `const string_type input_string` the `const` is ignored for typedef. So you are trying to convert `const wchar_t*` to a `wchar_t*`. 
If you change`typedef wchar_t* string_type;` to `typedef const wchar_t* string_type;` it should compile.

`const string_type input_string` would look like `wchar_t *const input_string` whereas you expected `const wchar_t*`. You can see this by changing `const wchar_t *str` to `wchar_t *const str` and it will also work.

Comment: "... the const is ignored ...". Could you be more precise on why that const is ignored (or not taken into account in the conversion) ?

Comment: @J.N.: that `const` in `string_token_stream(const string_type input_string)` makes `input_string` const, not what it points to. If you try to assign to `input_string` anything inside the function, the compiler will give you an error something like `assignment of read-only parameter 'input_string'`. I think this comes from the fact that `const/volatile type` and `type const/volatile` are equivalent, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @Alex : yes, thanks, I figured it out by myself, there was a related question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561666/cannot-convert-parameter-conversion-loses-qualifiers), in pseudo code:

```
"const string_type" <=> "const (char *)" <=> char const *      and not "(const char) *".
```

So, `const wchar_t*` can't be converted to `const string_type`.